# How to toggle a checkbox when ng-repeat is used?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem using a switch when it is in a set of switches generated by ng-repeat. My objective is to trigger an alert when each individual checkbox is clicked.

For example, when I click the switch to enable it should alert "1", and off should alert "0", but when I click the switch to enable it alerts "1" and when i click the other switch to enable it alerts "0".

[Here is a plunkr with a sample single switch](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kc8M3enHJB7iwFRyGUDr?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="switchdemo">
  <h1>On Off switch using Angular JS</h1>
  <div ng-controller="DemoController" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="well">
 <label class="switch" >
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Token" ng-change="changeStatus();">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
              </div>
        <div class="well">
       <label class="switch" >
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Token" ng-change="changeStatus();">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label></div>
    <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('switchdemo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope){

  $scope.init = function(){
    $scope.status = 1;
  }

  $scope.changeStatus = function(){
    $scope.status = !$scope.status;
    if($scope.status==1) {
      $scope.status=1;
      alert($scope.status);
    }
      else
      {
        $scope.status=0;
         alert($scope.status);
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Token" ng-change="changeStatus(Token);">
</div>
```

in javascript and you will got true/false into alert refer link  http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/18311/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.changeStatus = function(data){
        alert(data)
    };
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer, but when i add another checkbox, both of them was checked.

Comment: yes, but i need to insert this function inside a ng-repeat :)

Comment: Brother in ng-repeat it will work too just pass value into function into ng-repeat

Comment: Your welcome and accept as a answer for ng-repea follow the link http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/18321/